# Passing $.getJSON object to another ember controller

Tags: javascript, json, object, ember.js

So I'm struggling to get this to work. Maybe my approach is not good. I'm quite a noob at using a Frontend framework like ember.js.

So, I've got a $.getJSON request obtaining a JSON data from a local file. The problem is that I need to pass this data, not to the template but to another object inside one ember controller.

I'm trying to use ember-CLI-charts to I need to return the object in the last lines of the property.

```
diffData: Ember.computed('model', function(){

    let url = "log_hr24_diff.json";
    let diff_data = Ember.$.getJSON(url);         

    return {
      labels: ['Difficulty', 'Date'],
      datasets: [
      {
        label: "Difficulty",
        data: diff_data
        },
        {
        label: "Date",
        data: date_data
        }
      ]
    }
})
```

So that is not working. Either do this:

```
let diff_data = Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data){
   return Ember.Object.create(data);
});
```

So how do I get the JSON object from the `diff_data` JSON response to pass it to the return object?

Tried and search it a lot, but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes more sense to create a *service*, that way you can consume(in simpler words "use") your getJson call inside many controllers (or components and models), and change the url each time if you wish. 
It makes sense when looking at making your code reusable.
To do this, you'll want to make a service through the CLI.

```
Ember g service someServiceName
```

Then your service  might look a little like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
    getUrlData(url){

    let data = Ember.$.getJSON(url);

    return data.then((json) => {

      let records = [];
      json.forEach(function(item){        
        records.push(item);        
      });

      return records;
    });
  }

});
```

For any advanced readers, i've avoided destructuring(ie - using a const) to avoid confusion for the OP.

And back in your controller, you may write something similar to:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

serviceToUse: Ember.inject.service('some-service-name'), 
diffData: Ember.computed('model', function(){   

    let url = "log_hr24_diff.json";
    let diff_data = this.get('serviceToUse').getUrlData(url);

        //parse returnedData or put it in a new variable to use as you see fit.
        return {
            labels: ['Difficulty', 'Date'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Difficulty",
                    data: diff_data
                },
                {
                    label: "Date",
                    data: date_data
                }
            ]
        }           
})
```

Now in the handlebar file for this controller, you can access the data from your controller like so:

```
{{diffData.labels}} //outputs "Difficulty,Date". You can loop through the datasets property yourself.
```

Beginner's hint - file names should match each other, that's how Ember knows how to link files. This does not always have to be true, but for now stick to that rule.

This should get you where you want to go. It works on my machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've got another way of getting this working, but your approach seems more reusable. Many thanks for spending time in this!

Comment: I've updated my approach in another post. Let me know what do you think! Thanks! @oisinfoley

Answer (score 1):

So finally I found the correct way its mean to be coded in ember (or a way to do it).

I realized that I need to return the diff and date data into the model. So i've done this.

> routes/index.js

```
url = "log_hr24_diff.json";
var diff_data = Ember.$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    return Ember.Object.create(data);
});

url = "log_hr24_dates.json"
var dates_data = Ember.$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    return Ember.Object.create(data);
});

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      price: price_data,
      chart_diff: diff_data,
      chart_dates: dates_data
    });
  },
});
```

Then in the main index controller file, just use this model data to pass the json data to the correct final object:

> controllers/index.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  applicationController: Ember.inject.controller('application'),

  diffData: Ember.computed('model', function(){
    return {
      labels: this.get('model.chart_dates'),
      datasets: [
      {
        label: "Difficulty",
        data: this.get('model.chart_diff')
        }
      ]
    }
  })

});
```

So that's for me a correct way of doing things out on ember. Getting data in the model, passing data into the controller for logic workarround and finally pass the resulting object to the view.

Comment: Hi David. One last thing to could try is to create an array called "Urls", and put "log_hr24_diff.json" and "log_hr24_dates.json" inside this new array.Then you could do create another array to hold the data that comes back from the getJSON calls(could maybe call it "jsonDatasets". Finally you'd do a foreach on the "Urls" array, meaning you would only write "Ember.$.getJSON" one time, meaning you don't repeat yourself. Inside the foreach, you use .push() to push the result of the first url into the first index position of "jsonDatasets". Sets the code up for more urls later in the future.

Comment: @OisinFoley Ok.I will do that! Thanks for the advice!